# Tranport Agent: How do I know which group an email belong to?

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-transport-agents

I'm trying to write transport agent for Exchange Server 2019. I want to apply policy for a group email But I don't know How do I know which group an email belong to.

For example: test01 belong to Dev group.

How can I Know that.